# ProtectedLocalStorage SetAsync hangs indefinitely on await

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, blazor

## Problem

ProtectedLocalStorage injected property hangs when trying to set a property.  I was able to replicate with a default server Blazor app with the following code in the front page:

```cs
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
Welcome to your new app.
<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?"/>

<button @onclick="TestLocalStorage">@GetValue</button>

@code {

    [Inject]
    ProtectedLocalStorage LocalStorage { get; set; }

    private int counter;

    public int GetValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (counter > 0)
            {
                var inte = LocalStorage.GetAsync<int>("counter");
                return inte.Result.Value;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private async Task TestLocalStorage()
    {
        counter++;
        await LocalStorage.SetAsync("counter", counter);
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

If you click debug and stop at `counter++` and try to step through the code, you'll find that it just hangs on `await LocalStorage.SetAsync("counter", counter);`

What am I doing wrong?

## EDIT

With the first answer I misunderstood what the answer was saying and thought the "SetAsync" method of `ProtectedLocalStorage` was re-rendering the component it was executed in, when really what was happening was that I was using an Async method in the parent component that would then cause the base component to invoke the state change method that would then re-calculate the property that was using the wrong async method to fetch a result from `ProtectedLocalStorage`.  Because that second execution to the getter caused a deadlock, it was not readily visible on Debug what was happening making it appear it would just lock up on trying to save any ProtectedLocalStorage variable using `await async`.  I am now clear on the problem.

Essentially my original thinking was correct that ProtectedLocalStorage doesn't affect component rendering, I was tripping up over buggy code that confused me on the lifecycle of a component, and my frustration got the better of me.  However, I have working code now and am moving right along on the project without much hitch.  Those in the answers, thank you for you patience and help.

### NOTE on ASYNC and Deadlocks

As some have suggested, I'm aware of deadlocks and Async calls.  The `.Result` is poor code and I'm certainly not suggesting that that is proper code nor code I should use.  The `Deadlock` answers on SO do not satisfy this particular post because I understand how that works and is actually a bug that doesn't require me to get on Stackoverflow to fix.  The true issue I was facing was a mishap in understanding the lifecycle of a component rendering mechanism and the true root cause that was answered in the accepted answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['await' works, but calling task.Result hangs/deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks)

Comment: @Charlieface - no.  It's the detail that `await ProtectedLocalStorage.SendAsync` rerenders Blazor components which was unexpected behavior to me.  My thinking was that it wouldn't do that.  Regardless, the lock really is just me quickly printing the value.  Let's put it this way, if I knew it that it rerendered then I'd know how to fix the Result lock, and I wouldn't have made this post.  :)

Comment: End of the day, you need to follow best practice and that is to never call `.Result` in the first place. That's the root of every async deadlock you ever see.

Comment: @Charlieface - well I appreciate the advice and to be honest, the post is a quick summary of the issue.  I'm going to keep the .Result in the post because it helps illustrate the problem however, as I always try to keep up with best practices, I'll take that consideration.

Comment: @PaulCarlton [Polite]  I don't think providing an answer to your question in the question is good practice.  Everything gets muddled up.  You can't separate out comments on the question from comments on the answer.  If you feel you need to provide a different answer to those already provided, it should be as an answer.  See my answer on your incorrect  **Edit** statement that ""SetAsync" rerenders the components.".

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - hello, yeah I think I should just delete the answer and then describe where I misunderstood and then edit the question again so that it reflects factual information in light of your answer.  Thank you very much for your insight in your answer, that was a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question **Edit** states:

> So apparently, and I didn't know this: "SetAsync" rerenders the components. I'm not sure why and I'd really like to know why?

Not true.

The `ComponentBase` UI handler re-renders the component.  `TestLocalStorage` is the handler for `<button @onclick="TestLocalStorage">@GetValue</button>`.

The handler implemented by `ComponentBase` looks like this:

```cs
async Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem item, object? obj)
{
    var uiTask = item.InvokeAsync(obj);

    var isCompleted = uiTask.IsCompleted || uiTask.IsCanceled;

    if (!isCompleted)
    {
        this.StateHasChanged();
        await uiTask;
    }

    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

`SetAsync` is a true async routine and yields.  It's running on the UI thread [the Synchronisation Context] so the yield allows the next queued activity to execute.  This is the render queued by calling `StateHasChanged`: the Renderer renders the component.  Once `SetAsync` completes, the handler executes to completion, calls `StateHasChanged` and the component is rendered a second time.

To demonstrate override the existing handler with this one in your component.

```cs
async Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem item, object? obj)
{
    await item.InvokeAsync(obj);
}
```

Now you have to manually call `StateHasChanged` in `TestLocalStorage` to renfer the component.

See this answer for more detail - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76729783/13065781

Comment: AHAH!  Ok I got it now.  That's making the light bulb turn on.  I swear I'm not dim, I'm just not in my best way and being on a time crunch doesn't really help.  But this certainly clears it up as root cause.  I will update my answer so that it better reflects factual information.

Comment: No Problem.  On the surface components appear simple.  They're far, far from it!

Comment: Absolutely, agreed!  May not be apparent, but I do realy like Blazor and reusable components.  The last larger more complex app was event driven with an architecture based a db backend and on a message bus system, works fantastically well updating a lot of information to the UI instantly and often.  The data flow was such that this kind of problem never surfaced.  It's kind of ironic that a smaller, way more simpler and much less critical app that requires some cookie data storage makes this problem crop up unexpectedly (thread lock).  I do appreciate your time and help!

Comment: The rule I preach is stick to **Async and Await** unless you REALLY know what you're doing.  `.Result` and `.Wait()` are disasters waiting to happen!  There are a few articles out there on the subject [including this one of mine that provides references to several others - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5276310/Async-Programming-in-Blazor].

Answer (score 1):

When you `await` on LocalStorage.SetAsync() then Blazor will re-render. All render code is sync but yours uses `.Result`. That will deadlock with the InvokeAsync line.

General .net/C# : avoid `.Result` and `.Wait()` in async code.

Blazor: avoid async code in the render section

Comment: It never gets there because `await LocalStorage.SetAsync("counter", counter)` hangs indefinitely.  It ties up the current running thread and doesn't go to the next line on debug so `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` doesn't get called and the property that fetches the value from local storage is never computed.

Comment: I hadn't spotted the use of GetValue. The problem is clear now.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, that's starting to make a lot more sense to me.  I'm going to try a different approach.

Comment: After doing some analysis and reworked a couple things, I was able to arrive to a solution based on this answers information on `SetAsync` rerendering components (which is unexpected behavior for me).  I am accepting your answer, thank you for your patience, I was very frustrated when posting this question and now things have subsided and am finally moving onto the duty of programming the business logic without meddling about framework related issues.

Comment: SetAsync() itself has nothing to do with the rendering. But any `await` will allow queued renders to be performed. Search for "Blazor Event Lifecycle".