# In Blazor, to get the GUI to refresh, why do I need to change a function signature from void to async task?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In the context of Blazor framework, could someone explain me why the GUI is not refresh when calling the first function but why it works with the second version:

**version 1:**

```csharp
private void ValidateButtonClicked()
    {
        if (_userAnswer.Value == "") return;
        var iUserAnswer = int.Parse(_userAnswer.Value);

        var iAnswer = _questions[_questionNumber].Result;

        if (iUserAnswer == iAnswer)
        {
            _userAnswer = new MarkupString(_userAnswer.Value + "<span style='color:green'>\u2713</span>");
        }
        else
        {
            _userAnswer = new MarkupString(_userAnswer.Value + "<span style='color:red'>\u274C</span>");
        }

    AskQuestion();
    }
```

```csharp
private async Task ValidateButtonClicked()
    {
        if (_userAnswer.Value == "") return;
        var iUserAnswer = int.Parse(_userAnswer.Value);

        var iAnswer = _questions[_questionNumber].Result;

        if (iUserAnswer == iAnswer)
        {
            _userAnswer = new MarkupString(_userAnswer.Value + "<span style='color:green'>\u2713</span>");
        }
        else
        {
            _userAnswer = new MarkupString(_userAnswer.Value + "<span style='color:red'>\u274C</span>");
        }

    await Task.Delay(1000);  // using async and await allows the GUI to refresh 
    AskQuestion();
    }
```

Comment: It Depends on what AskQuestion() is doing. How long does it take? Try setting up a proper [mre].

Comment: And `Task.Delay(1);` is long enough.

Comment: See this answer for some more detail on UI Event Handling - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76729783/13065781

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - you can edit the top banner and add links there.

Comment: @ℍℍ - thanks, didn't know you could do thar.